# Making an Ubuntu 22.04 based desktop and server distribution?

Tags: server, compiling, iso, customization, custom-distributions

I am a beginner in Ubuntu.

How can I make an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop and server based distribution?

Comment: Give the beginner a break. We all know that he is referring to 22.04.

Comment: what do you mean with the question? How to install Ubuntu? Or how to make your own version with a diff. set of software?

Comment: How to install https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: If you want to have additional "server specific" software (if there's any) then just install it in a desktop version. Server is just a variant without a desktop because it isn't needed for the typical server tasks but one can be installed to, making it indistinguishable from the aforementioned suggestion. I think you're approaching this as if "server" and "desktop editions were fundamentally different which is wrong, they're fundamentally the same.

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd?answertab=modifieddesc) See specifically [C.S.Cameron's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307835/618353) since it's the only one working with recent Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some confusion in your question. The major difference between a desktop and server install is that the server does not have a graphical user interface. There are different questions asked at install time, but that is just to help you choose packages that are common on servers.

However, if what you want is a graphical UI, and then run some service on it (such as MySQL, or Apache, or load Docker containers), then the desktop version of Ubuntu runs just fine. Indeed, this is exactly what I have. I run 3 different database services, a webserver supporting 9 different websites, I used to have an email service running on it, I run 7 different docker containers.

So, go ahead, install desktop, and the choose the packages you want from the package installer. All should be just fine.